# Getting specific content from a file

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following data in format.

```
##############################
# A_Data
##############################
A_Data += data1
data2
data3
data4

###############################
# B_Data
###############################
B_Data += data5
data6

###############################
# C_Data
###############################
C_Data += data7
```

I want to extract out data separately like:

```
A_Data (e.g.Array)
data1
data2
data3
data4
```

and similarly for B_data and C_Data so that i can display it separately.
With my script, I am able to get

```
A_Data += data1
data2
data3
data4

B_Data += data5
data6

C_Data += data7
```

I know its case of multi-line mode, and I have googled it many times, but I am unable to get it.
Please help me out with this as I am new to use regular expressions in perl.

What I have tried so far :

I put the file data in an array and then tried to apply regex

```
@array1;
for (my $i=0;$i < $length;$i++)
{
    $data[$i]=~ s/#.*//;
    #$data[$i]=~ /[A_Data](.*?)[B_Data]/;  ## trying to get data in between those two data.
    print $data[$i]."\n";
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'd use multiline regexes for that.  An expression to parse out the individual lines themselves.  But I'd do the state transitions manually.

Comment: It is not obvious what you have tried or what you need help with. Please edit your question.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Sure, I just updated to show what I have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

The solution depends on the precise format of your data file, but this works fine for the example you gave

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'data_file.txt' or die $!;

my $tag;
my $data;

while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  s/#.*//;
  next unless /\S/;
  $tag = $1 if s/^(\w+)\s*\+=\s*//;
  push @{ $data->{$tag} }, $_ if $tag;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd $data;
```

**output**

```
{
  A_Data => ["data1", "data2", "data3", "data4"],
  B_Data => ["data5", "data6"],
  C_Data => ["data7"],
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this is the type of manual state transition solution Michael Wilson suggested in comments.

Comment: The `use Data::Dump` and `dd` lines are for diagnostics, they can be removed or replaced.

Comment: @iDev: Then you haven't copied the code correctly. Have you written `use Data::Dumper` instead? As Joel says this is just to display the accumulated data and you can omit it, but it's very useful to be certain your code is working as expected